# Agm map marker not display markers

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm using angular 4 and agm map marker i have create marker put it's not working,
i have put the code below please tel any one how to fix it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IDashItem } from '../../../Interface/dashitem';
import { DashService } from '../../../services/dash.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
//export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number = -43.9509;
  lng: number = -34.4618;
  zoom: number = 4;
  //httpdata: any;  
  constructor(private dashservice: DashService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    return this.dashservice.getdashitem().subscribe(Response => {
      this.httpdata = Response;
      console.log(this.httpdata)
    })
  }

}
interface marker{
  name?: string;
  lat?: number;
  lng?: number;
  draggable?: boolean;
}
```

**map.components.html**

```
<!-- Heading Row -->
      <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [zoomControl]="false" (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">
            <agm-marker 
              *ngFor ="let map of httpdata; let i = index"
              (markerClick)="clickedMarker(map, i)"
              [latitude]="map.address.geo.lat" 
              [longitude]="map.address.geo.lng">
            </agm-marker>
          </agm-map>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <app-bn-tagline></app-bn-tagline>
        <div *ngFor ="let map of httpdata; let i = index">
            <label>{{map.address.geo.lat}}</label>
            <label>{{map.address.geo.lng}}</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The `httpdata` variable is being resolved asynchronously. Would you try changing this line in map.components.html:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor ="let map of httpdata; let i = index"
```

with:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let map of (httpdata | async); let i = index"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, so tried the above answer given by @user1183098 but it didn't work for me. So I fixed this using below concept:-
`Here the problem is due to async data coming from services.So you can do something like store the data coming from services first in some variable (let say httpData) then after the completion of that method, trigger a function which will return the data saved in the variable httpData.`
Now replace `httpdata` with `httpData` in your above given angular code.